# Why does my Data selector have a side effect?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a small visualization using D3 and need to bind several different things to the same data element. I had a point where the only way I seemed to be able to get this to work however was by carrying out multiple calls to `Data()` which I felt was probably inefficient.

As an example here's my join code:

```
// Sort out the data joins
var joinedGroups = segments.selectAll(".menu").data(pie(data));
var joinedSegments = segments.selectAll(".menu-segment").data(pie(data));
var joinedIcons = segments.selectAll("circle").data(pie(data));
```

Here's an image to help illustrate what I was building:

[image]

In my DOM you can see how these relate:

- joinedGroups = `<g>`
- joinedSegments = `<path>`
- joinedIcons = `<circle>`

Here is an output from the DOM to illustrate:

```
<g class="menu">
       <path class="menu-segment" d="" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></path>
       <circle r="5" cx="29.999999999999996" cy="-51.96152422706632"></circle>  
</g>
```

I was then using the `joinedGroups` to add new `<g>`, `<path>` and `<circle>` elements. At that point I switched to using `joinedSegments` to update my pie segments. This is the bit that I felt was wrong:

```
// Update existing segments and icons
joinedSegments.attr("d", arc);
joinedIcons.attr("cx", function(d) { return calcMidPoint(d).x; })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return calcMidPoint(d).y; });
```

After thinking about this I concluded that I should be able to now take my `joinedGroups` and select all the `.menu-segment` instances, to get my all that `<path>` elements instead.

```
joinedGroups.selectAll(".menu-segment").attr("d", arc);
```

At this point I thought I cracked it, I was no longer using `joinedSegments` so I took out the `Data()` call at the top, and then it stopped working correctly, missing out a segment that should be there. So I'm left a little confused about the side-effects of calling `Data()` - can anyone explain what's going on?

You can see an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/s51mt3tv/) here - commenting out lines **#123 & #124** illustrate the side-effect of calling `Data()` that I'm referring too, as the yellow segment will disappear.

Comment: The only side effect of `.data()` is that it binds the data passed as an argument to the elements in the selection. Maybe your selection doesn't contain some elements that should be there and you're binding the wrong data when commenting the lines?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I can't see how that could be the case - each bind occurs on exactly the same data and there is a single `<g>`, `<path>` and `<circle>` for each data item. I'm not using the result of that `data()` join anywhere, yet without it a whole segment goes missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that you have nested elements, and each of them (`g`, `path`, and `circle`) needs to have the data bound to them because you're setting attributes based on the data.

You're binding the data to the `g` elements explicitly (line 122), so that works fine. Everything works fine for the enter selection as well, as `.append()` has the side effect of "inheriting" the bound data to the appended elements. The problem is with the update selection. The `.selectAll()` (lines 143 and 144) you're using to select the nested elements and update their attributes does *not* update the bound data, which you're relying on in the functions to set the attribute values.

There's two ways of solving this. The first is what you already have -- select those nested elements explicitly and update their data. This however requires additional code and relies on the ordering of the nested elements being the same as their parents, which is not guaranteed.

A better way is to simply replace `.selectAll()` in lines 143 and 144 with `.select()`. This is possible because you have only a single element of each type nested underneath the `g`, so the selection contains only a single element anyway. The main difference between `.selectAll()` and `.select()` in this case is that while `.selectAll()` does not update the data bound to the selected elements, `.select()` does. The effect is the same as with your current solution -- the data bound to the nested elements is updated correctly, except that you don't need any additional code and don't rely on an order of the selected elements.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s51mt3tv/15/).

Comment: Lars - thanks very much. That's a great explanation (which I almost completely understand). I've been reading http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/ which I'd never seen before which is also helping and your answer has made a few things click. Thank you :)

Comment: The basic problem wasn't the side effects, it was the lack thereof (because you used `.selectAll()`) ;)